# fetching contents of json file and modifying the content using ansible

Tags: ansible

I have JSON file with contents

> env_variables.json

```
{ "server": "{{server}}" , "notes": "{{notes}}" }
```

and ansible-playbook as below: (to upload a lambda with the environment variables)

> playbook.yml

```
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    server: localhost
    notes: hello this is localhost
  tasks:
    - name: Lambda creation/updation
      lambda:
        name: ansible_test
        state: present
        region: "eu-west-1"
        role: 'arn:aws:iam::xyz:role/xyz_lambda'
        zip_file: '{{ item.path }}'
        runtime: 'python3.6'
        environment_variables: "{{ lookup('file','/env_variables.json') | from_json }}"
        handler: 'lambda_function.lambda_handler'
```

How can I use the above-mentioned **"env_variables.json"** file format to insert the environment variables with values mentioned in the ***"vars"*** directive of **playbook.yml**?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`include_vars`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/modules/include_vars_module.html)  for that.

```
- name: Load data from json
  include_vars: file=/env_variables.json
```

If this file is outside of normal lookup pathes, you can use [`set_fact`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/modules/set_fact_module.html) module:

```
- name: Load data from json
  set_fact:
    loaded_data: '{{ lookup('file','/env_variables.json') | from_json }}'
```

Comment: Thank you @George Shuklin for the reply, I have one more question, what if the lamda task is on a loop where I'm finding the .zip files in a repository and each .zip is associated with different env_variables.json, How can i dynamically create that variable and use it to upload lambda